# Yet another question on `Wifi and Bluetooth not working together`

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa

Facing issues with audio from Bluetooth earphones in 20.04. Initial pairing works fine, once I stop the initial audio source (by pausing), the audio comes distorted/crackling and also skipping from Bluetooth earphones.
If the connection is switched over to HSP/HFP(really bad sound quality though) it works fine and after a while, I can switch back to A2DP.
Not sure where the problem is

- PulseAudio?
- alsa?
- or Bluetooth drivers?

The problem only occurs in Bluetooth earphones. Willing to give more details and stats if anyone can guide me.

Temporary Solution:

- Switch to HFS for a few seconds (keep the audio source on the play) and then switch to A2DP from Settings menu

Some usefule info:

---

`suds lshw -c network`

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 03
       serial: c4:b3:01:89:db:3a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=192.168.1.29 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:c1200000-c1207fff memory:c1000000-c11fffff
```

---

`iwconfig`

```
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"net+"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: B0:95:75:A1:0F:59   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

---

`lsmod | grep wl`

```
wl                   6455296  0
cfg80211              704512  1 wl
```

There's no `iwlwifi` module loaded

This is also related to `wifi and bluetooth` not working simultaneously.
This didn't help

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"
```

maybe because there's no `iwlwifi` module loaded. It exists and I can manually load but not sure if that will change things.